# getComputedStyle() not working in Gatsby despite being wrapped in loadable-component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, p5.js

Pretty new to it / react.js in general. I'm trying to incorporate some sketches I've made using p5.js, for which I'm using the plugin react-p5-wrapper. I am also using the loadable-components plugin to allow it to do SSR despite Gatsby being CSR.

The sketches are loading, however, I am still unable to use functions like `getComputedStyle()` to access the CSS values of the elements of my page. These are integral to my sketches (allows them to scale/resize properly), and I don't understand why they aren't working despite being wrapped in loadable-component.

This is what i'm using to do SSR on my p5 sketches:

```
import loadable from "@loadable/component"

const LoadableP5 = loadable(() => import('react-p5-wrapper'), {
  resolveComponent: ({ReactP5Wrapper}) => ReactP5Wrapper,
});
```

These lines, for example, produce an error when I run Gatsby:

```
const unit = frameRef.current.getComputedStyle();
const trueWidth = parseFloat(unit.getPropertyValue("width"));
```

When I take out anything that attempts to use the window it works fine. Not sure how to deal with this. As you can see i'm using refs to get out of using getElementByID, but still no luck.

I would appreciate any advice at all, very new to Gatsby / React and have been stuck on this issue for days.

Comment: `frameRef.current.getComputedStyle();` should be `getComputedStyle(frameRef.current);`